# Can I directly invoke the Spring exception resolvers?

Tags: java, spring, exception

My servlet request thread invokes a worker thread that can throw exceptions of many possible types. The worker thread catches any exception and passes it back to the request thread. I'd like to get that exception to the correct handler method in my Spring controller.

You cannot rethrow an exception from one thread in another thread, so the request thread wraps the original exception and throws that. That wrapper exception is currently being handled by a catch-all controller method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)`. Because this handler exists, Spring does not look at the nested exception, so the nested exception is ignored.

I can add a handler for the wrapper exception type. In that, I'd like to unwrap the nested exception and ask Spring to route it to the correct handler. I've learned that Spring handles exceptions via a chain of resolvers that implement `HandlerExceptionResolver`. Is there a way I can invoke that chain directly from my handler?

Answer (score 1):

Inject `List<HandlerExceptionResolver> handlerExceptionResolvers` into your controller, then go through the list and try to handle the exception. If it returns a non-null ModelAndView, this means the request has been handled:

```
    Exception e = ...;
    if(e != null) 
        for (HandlerExceptionResolver resolver : handlerExceptionResolvers) 
            if (resolver.resolveException(req, resp, null, e) != null)
                return null;
```

Comment: Actually, my exception-handler methods are in the controller itself, so it's easy to call them directly. The problem is in knowing which one to call. I have many possible nested exception types, each with its own handler method, and I really don't want a big ```if instanceof else if instanceof``` structure that checks them all. And how would people know to update it when they add new exception types?

Comment: @FranzAmador, got it now. I updated the answer, try it out. I just debugged what Srpging MVC is doing and repeated some of it.

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav, that looks like just what I need. Let me try it out...

Comment: Unfortunately not. In my environment, the third arg to resolveException needs to be the original handlerMethod, which I don't have available to pass. Null doesn't work for me. I've been investigating an alternate idea of overriding our ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver to have it unwrap other-thread exceptions and invoke itself recursively on them.